# Vertically centering the search bar and button in a header

Tags: html, css, forms, svg, header

I'm trying to center the search bar and button in the header so that it will alaways vertically centered with the SVG logo but can't figure it out by myself.
Would appreciate the help.
Thanks in advance!

```css
header {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #333333;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.clear {
  display: inline;
}

.LogoHeader {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 25%;
  width: 25%;
  border-spacing: 20px;
  vertical-align: -5px;
  margin-left: 47px;
}

.SearchForm {
  text-align: right;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 0px
}

.SearchField {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.SearchButton {
  display: inline;
  background-color: deeppink;
  border-style: none;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#website" class="clear" style=" margin-left: 47px;"><img class="LogoHeader" src="C:\Users\David\Desktop\WebDevelopmentTest\images\NotWalla\logo.svg" alt="My news website"></a>
  <span>
                <form class="SearchForm";>
                    <input class="SearchField" type="text" name="q" value autocomplete="off">
                    <input class="SearchButton" type="submit" value="Search">
                </form>
        </span>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `vertical-align: -5px;` to `vertical-align: middle;`.

Answer (score 3):

to vertically centralize elements you can use on parents elements

```
display:flex;     align-items:center;
```

E.g:

```
<div style="display:flex;     align-items:center;"> 
<div> 1 </div>
<div> 2 </div>
<div> 3 </div>
</div>
```

and if you want to center horizontally elements you can add

```
justify-content: center;
```

Working example
https://jsfiddle.net/2fe2yr87/

Comment: Thank you it works for me. You just have to set the height to 100% in the sytle attribute.